# Is there a Spark SQL Only solution to apply cast to a complex column(map,struct)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is there a Spark SQL Only solution to apply cast to a complex column as below:

```
amap    map<bigint,struct<dname1:string,dval1:decimal(38,18)>>
```

I want the casted column to look like below (just decimal precision casting actually)

```
amap    map<bigint,struct<dname1:string,dval1:decimal(18,5)>>
```

I am looking for a Spark-SQL only solution, something like:

```
SELECT CAST(amap as <NOTSUREWHAT>) AS casted_map from ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DDL string directly:

```sql
SELECT CAST(
  amap as map<bigint,struct<dname1:string,dval1:decimal(38,18)>>
) AS casted_map from ...
```